# If conditional with no comparison infinitely executing

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements

In the code

```
 while(true)
 {
    this.rv1 = pdata.ReadString();
    this.rv2 = pdata.ReadLong();
    if(false)
    {
       continue;
    }
    break;
 }
```

Why does `if(false)` infinitely execute, while other languages such as python's `if False: Do.Something()` never execute?

I didn't write the code in question, but I can't proceed without being able to read it - and I'm no AS3 pro!

Comment: You don't need the `continue` statement here. It will never execute. But the `while(true)` itself will execute indefinitely until ended by `break`.

Comment: What happens exactly? The loop runs 1 time or infinite?

Comment: @ppasler It runs infinitely, causing a 2030 EOFError in pdata, and the `while(true)` seen here is the only loop in the function.

Comment: @xotikorukx pretty sure, that you are wrong. The loop in the code you provided can't execute more than 1 time. You can use traces or try to debug it and you will see it.

Comment: Could you not just remove the if statement, because it never executes as it's checking for `false`, which will never be `true`. Or if you need the code to run just once, like it seems in this while loop, could you just remove the while loop entirely?

Comment: For the last time, no I could not remove any statement. It's not my code, I'm only tasked with reading it, I physically cannot modify it. If I could remove it, this question wouldn't be here. The next best thing I can do is post the whole function and the data that is parsed in it.

Comment: 1) The code shown will execute only once, it does not loop.  2) The problem is in one of your pdata.ReadXXX() calls, and is either crashing, which makes it appear to be an infinite loop, or there is more code before this that keeps calling it over and over.  3) "For the last time...", assuming you are not an English speaker, is a pretty serious statement when you never said anything for the first time!  Don't be rude, people are here helping you for free